# Is stripe really this simple or am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I just implemented stripe and the whole thing seems to easy/simple to be true. Am I missing something? I just have a new.html.erb view and new and create actions in my controller.

My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("pk_test_uZ5i6q4hDYctglEMPYiqLUh5");
</script>

    <div class = 'charge-form'>
      <span class="payment-errors"></span>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <input value="<%= current_user.email if current_user %>" type="hidden" data-stripe="email" >
        </label>
      </div>

         <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Full name</span><span class = 'small-text'> (e.g. John Smith)</span>
          <input type="text" size="5" data-stripe="name"  class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Country</span><span class = 'small-text'> (e.g. United States)</span>
          <input type="text" size="10" data-stripe="address_country" class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Address</span>
          <input type="text" size="10" data-stripe="address_line1" class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Postal Code / Zip Code</span>
          <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="address_zip" class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Card Number</span>
          <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
          <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" class ='form-field-expiry'>
          <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year" class ='form-field-expiry'>
        </label>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>
          <span>CVC</span>
          <input type="text" size="3" data-stripe="cvc" class = 'form-field'>
        </label>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="c-btn-submit-charge" value="Submit Payment">
        </div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    $form.submit(function(event) {
      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
      $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
      // Request a token from Stripe:
      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
      // Prevent the form from being submitted:
      return false;
    });
  });
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    // Grab the form:
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    if (response.error) { // Problem!
      // Show the errors on the form:
      $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
      $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission
    } else { // Token was created!
      // Get the token ID:
      var token = response.id;
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
      // Submit the form:
      $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };
</script>
```

My Charges controller:

```
    def new 

    end


    def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 2000



    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
        # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:email],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

      Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount => @amount,
          :currency => 'usd',
          :customer => customer.id,
          :description => 'Example charge custom form'
      )

      current_user.subscribed = true
      current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
      current_user.expiry_date = Date.today + 90.days
      current_user.save


      flash[:success] = "Thank you for subscribing. Your account has been unlocked."
      redirect_to root_path

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end


end
```

Comment: Did you try it? It looks fine to me, but I'm not testing it if you haven't. :)

Comment: I did try it and it worked for test cards! But i dunno I just don't want to screw up for the real thing.

Comment: Whatever it does when given test cards is what it will do given live cards (and using your Live Secret Key).  Is there a particular part you're concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

The way to verify if it is working or not is to check if you can see the transactions or subscriptions on your Stripe account website. Make sure to use one of Stripe's test cards when making charges or signing up for subscriptions.

The reason it seems so simple is because this code is hiding what is happening behind the scenes. In the code you posted, when you do something like create a customer, it creates the object in Ruby, but it also sends a request to the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers) and makes a customer on their end as well in their database. The same thing happens when you create a subscription; a subscription object is created in Ruby, and a request is sent to Stripe's API which creates a subscription on their end as well.